# Does server-side content security policy exist for youtube video player API, app, mod apks and website?

Tags: android, security, youtube, apk, android-youtube-api

Server-Side Configuration: The server sends CSP directives along with the web page or application content in the HTTP response headers. These directives specify rules and restrictions regarding the types of content that can be loaded and executed by the client.

Client-Side Enforcement: Upon receiving the CSP directives, the client (e.g., browser or app) interprets and enforces them. The client must adhere to these directives when loading resources, such as scripts, stylesheets, images, fonts, and other content, from the server.

Adhering to Restrictions: The client follows the rules specified in the CSP directives. For example, if the CSP specifies that scripts can only be loaded from specific domains, the client will only execute scripts from those domains and block any attempts to execute scripts from other sources.

Ensuring Secure Communication: CSP helps ensure secure communication between the client and the server by enforcing rules related to HTTPS usage and preventing certain types of attacks, such as cross-site scripting (XSS) and data injection.

Are the informations i wrote above correct for youtube itself?